# Pulseaudio module-combine-sink always throws Failure

Tags: alsa, bluez, pulseaudio

I am new to PulseAudio. As per my requirement, I need my audio output to be routed to either connected speaker, Bluetooth speaker, or both.

I am able to play the media file on speaker, or Bluetooth headset individually, however, I am not able to play on both.

I tried combining the two sinks, however, it always throws me the error:

> Failure: Module initialization failed

Here's is the code snippet:

`root@raspberrypi3:~# pactl list short sinks
1       palerts module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
2       pfeedback       module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
3       pringtones      module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
4       pmedia  module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
5       pdefaultapp     module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
6       peffects        module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
7       pvoicerecognition       module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
8       ptts    module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
9       pndk    module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
11      alsa_output.0.analog-stereo     module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
13      bluez_sink.FC_58_FA_F3_07_6F    module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED`

For music playback:

```
root@raspberrypi3:~# paplay abc.wav -d alsa_output.0.analog-stereo  
root@raspberrypi3:~# paplay abc.wav -d bluez_sink.FC_58_FA_F3_07_6F
```

Both work as per expectation.

However the problem is with the following statement:

`root@raspberrypi3:~# pactl load-module module-combine-sink sink-name=combine sink_properties=device.description=Combined slaves=alsa_output
.0.analog-stereo,bluez_sink.FC_58_FA_F3_07_6F
Failure: Module initialization failed`

I tried cleaning ~/.pulse directory, Commenting module-suspend-on-idle, but nothing seems to be of any help.
Any pointers will be of great help.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/91325

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the reason why it was not working.
On checking the logs of pulseaudio, I found that it was not able to find the module-combine-sink library.
I copied the libraries manually in /usr/lib/pulse-9.0/modules, restarted the pulseaudio, and it started working as expected, i.e. audio routed to both devices.